# How to hide previous commands/history in terminal and start like the beginning of the tab?

Tags: terminal

There should be a command on terminal that hides the history belongs a specific tab and lets you start from the beginning of the tab like it is new, but when you scroll up with a mouse you can see your history. I can't remember and find it online. I hope someone can tell it.

Comment: Ok, I've found it. it is kntrl+L

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear your terminal window:

- use the command `clear`to clear whatever is showing
- use `command+K` to clear everything

There are other things you can try too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198377/how-to-clear-previous-output-in-terminal-in-mac-os-x